# Dynamic Object Access from form to Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Here is my JavaScript with Ajax code:

Actually i am using this for dynamically adding option in any number of select in which this function is called.

```
function loadabc(vm) {
    var xmlhttp;    
    //alert(vm);

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else {
        // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    //alert("called");
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4) {
            var jsonObj = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
            for(i = 0; i < jsonObj.length; i++) {
                var createOption = document.createElement("option");
                //alert("Jeason has Passed Data");
                createOption.value = jsonObj[i].aId;
                createOption.text = jsonObj[i].aName;
                //alert("id" + createOption.value);
                //alert("Name" + createOption.text);
                document.impForm.vm.options.add(createOption);
                //alert("Added");
            }
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("get", "${pageContext.request.contextPath}/Admin_Search_con?flag=loaddetail", true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

I am using `ondblclick="loadabc(this)"` for calling it. I want to access this `vm` object for creating options in select. How can I do so?

Comment: Don't understand well what the problem is. Do you gen an error when trying to access *vm* within... where?

Comment: When i am passing this object in function , in alert it is displaying but when i am using it for  document.impForm.vm.options.add(createOption)   options are not created.

Comment: What does happen if you do vm.options.add(createOption) instead of document.impForm.vm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to use the param *vm* instead of referencing it as *document.impForm.vm*:

```
function loadabc(vm) {
  var xmlhttp;    
  //alert(vm);

  if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
      // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
      xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
  else {
      // code for IE6, IE5
      xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }

  //alert("called");
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4) {
          var jsonObj = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
          for(i = 0; i < jsonObj.length; i++) {
              var createOption = document.createElement("option");
              //alert("Jeason has Passed Data");
              createOption.value = jsonObj[i].aId;
              createOption.text = jsonObj[i].aName;
              //alert("id" + createOption.value);
              //alert("Name" + createOption.text);
              vm.options.add(createOption); // <-- Here!
              //alert("Added");
          }
      }
  }
  xmlhttp.open("get",  "${pageContext.request.contextPath}/Admin_Search_con?flag=loaddetail", true);
  xmlhttp.send();
}
```